# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 3 episode 19 at about 7:25?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What is the name of the song playing in *My Hero Academia* season 3 episode 19 at about 7:25?

Answer (score 0):

Mysterious - Soundtrack from My Hero Academia season 1

Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BuBZVTG4pU